# What are the benefits of flattening the 3-D array to 1-D array?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory-management, computer-science

I have a 3-D array represented in Java as

```
int[][][] arr = new int[X][Y][z]
```

If I try to implement the 3-D array using 1-D as

```
int[] oneDArray = new int[X*Y*Z]
```

index of an element arr[i][j][k] in 1-D will be calculated as

```
indx = X*Y*k + i*Y + j;
```

Though in the memory location the any N-D array will be stored sequentially.
With the 1-D, if I use three indexes (i,j,k) to access the elements, will this degrade the performance for larger values of X,Y,Z?

Comment: Java is not C, focusing on memory-management is not a productive use of your time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: I imagine the _1-d_ array is much faster.

Comment: Frankly, this smells of premature optimization.   Unless you know with great certainty that the 1D vs 3D performance difference *will* be critical ... you are probably wasting your time by trying to optimizing this too early.  The only way to be really sure that some aspect of your code is a bottleneck is to write an application benchmark and use a profiler **after** you have coded and tested your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[x][y][z]` involves 3 memory accesses, but very little computation.

`a[x * X * Y + y * Y + z]` involves one memory access, but more computation.

Generally, memory access is more expensive than a multiplication, very much so if the memory being accessed is not in the CPU cache.

For instance, if you repeatedly access random locations in an `int[][][]`, the first dimension will likely be in the CPU cache, but the other two won't be, for a total of 2 loads from main memory by element accessed. In contrast, using an `int[]` will involve only a single load from main memory, so will be up to twice as fast.

On the other hand, if you access your `int[][][]` sequentially, you will have very few cache misses, and an `int[]` will only be marginally faster.

All that said, switching to a 1-dimensional array makes the code harder to read and write, and unless the arrays are huge and accessed at great frequency, the performance difference will be too minor to matter.

To verify the theory, you can use the following benchmark:

```
public class Benchmark {

    public static void benchmark(String label, Code code) {
        print(25, label);
        
        try {
            for (int iterations = 1; ; iterations *= 2) { // detect reasonable iteration count and warm up the code under test
                System.gc(); // clean up previous runs, so we don't benchmark their cleanup
                long previouslyUsedMemory = usedMemory();
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                code.execute(iterations);
                long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
                long memoryUsed = usedMemory() - previouslyUsedMemory;
                
                if (iterations > 1E8 || duration > 1E9) { 
                    print(25, new BigDecimal(duration * 1000 / iterations).movePointLeft(3) + " ns / iteration");
                    print(30, new BigDecimal(memoryUsed * 1000 / iterations).movePointLeft(3) + " bytes / iteration\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    private static void print(int desiredLength, String message) {
        System.out.print(" ".repeat(Math.max(1, desiredLength - message.length())) + message);
    }
    
    private static long usedMemory() {
        var r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        return r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Code {
        /**
         * Executes the code under test.
         * 
         * @param iterations
         *            number of iterations to perform
         * @return any value that requires the entire code to be executed (to
         *         prevent dead code elimination by the just in time compiler)
         * @throws Throwable
         *             if the test could not complete successfully
         */
        Object execute(int iterations);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        benchmark(" int[][][] traversal, sequential", (iterations) -> {
            int n = (int) Math.pow(iterations, 1.0/3);
            int[][][] a = new int[n][n][n];
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
                        a[x][y][z] = x + y + z;
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;
        });
        benchmark("flat int[] traversal, sequential", (iterations) -> {
            int n = (int) Math.pow(iterations, 1.0/3);
            int[] a = new int[n * n * n];
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
                        a[(x * n + y) * n + z] = x + y + z;
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;
        });
        benchmark(" int[][][] traversal, unordered " , (iterations) -> {
            int n = (int) Math.pow(iterations, 1.0/3);
            int[][][] a = new int[n][n][n];
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
                        a[z][y][x] = x + y + z;
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;
        });
        benchmark("flat int[] traversal, unordered ", (iterations) -> {
            int n = (int) Math.pow(iterations, 1.0/3);
            int[] a = new int[n * n * n];
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
                        a[(z * n + y) * n + x] = x + y + z;
                    }
                }
            }
            return a;
        });
    }
}
```

On my computer, this prints:

```
  int[][][] traversal, sequential     1.406 ns / iteration      4.204 bytes / iteration
 flat int[] traversal, sequential     0.926 ns / iteration      3.984 bytes / iteration
  int[][][] traversal, unordered     11.716 ns / iteration      4.188 bytes / iteration
 flat int[] traversal, unordered      5.487 ns / iteration      3.984 bytes / iteration
```

As you can see, the performance differences only matter if you do millions of array accesses per second (or dozens of millions, if the access is sequential). The situations where one should replace an `int[][][]` with an `int[]` for performance reasons are therefore rare indeed.

Comment: Note to OP.  The above benchmark is artificial.  It may or may not be predictive of how the 1D vs 3D design choice affects *your* application.

Comment: The readability issue of a flattened array can be solved by encapsulating it in a class providing three-arg getters and four-arg setters. Another advantage of this approach is that you can change the implementation without the need to adapt the application, so you can test flattened arrays, three dimensional arrays, or the Foreign API with the real application easily.